# Cannot compile insight debugger on mingw64

Tags: c++, c, configure, mingw-w64, insight

I am trying to compile insight from source (git://sourceware.org/git/insight.git) on mingw64 (`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`).

These are my `./configure` options:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/arm-none-eabi-insight --target=arm-none-eabi --disable-binutils --disable-elfcpp --disable-gas --disable-gold --disable-gprof --disable-ld --disable-rpath --disable-zlib --enable-sim --with-expat --with-python --without-libunwind --with-tcl=/mingw64/lib --with-tk=/mingw64/lib
```

`make` output error:

```
[...]
  CXX    gdbtk/generic/gdbtk-bp.o
  CXX    gdbtk/generic/gdbtk-cmds.o
gdbtk/generic/gdbtk-cmds.c: In function 'int gdb_listfiles(ClientData, Tcl_Interp*, int, Tcl_Obj* const*)':
gdbtk/generic/gdbtk-cmds.c:1213:25: error: cannot convert 'listfiles_info' to 'void (*)(const char*, const char*, void*)'
 1213 |   map_symbol_filenames (info, false);
      |                         ^~~~
      |                         |
      |                         listfiles_info
In file included from gdbtk/generic/gdbtk-cmds.c:33:
./symfile.h:546:51: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void map_symbol_filenames(void (*)(const char*, const char*, void*), void*, int)'
  546 | void map_symbol_filenames (symbol_filename_ftype *fun, void *data,
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1629: gdbtk/generic/gdbtk-cmds.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/d/Work/FC/build_insight/insight/bundle/gdb'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:10110: all-gdb] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/d/Work/FC/build_insight/insight/bundle'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:866: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/Work/FC/build_insight/insight/bundle'
make: *** [Makefile:4: notarget] Error 2
```

How can I disable the gtk component? I have tried `./configure` with `--disable-gtk` but no success.

Comment: 1) What is your target board/CPU  2) what is the debug probe you are planning to use, if any ? As much as I liked it,  Insight is now dead (I guess):, it was last released ten years ago. You may want to consider maintained alternatives, such as Eclipse CDT or the Eclipse Standalone Debugger, or the TUI mode of GDB. Did you consider those?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this list of [GDB Front Ends](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends).

Comment: I managed to compile it on a Raspberry Pi 4 (arm) so I am convinced I can compile it with mingw64 on my desktop computer running Windows 10 (Intel processor)

Comment: What do you mean by debug probe?

Comment: I explicitly want Insight, not any other GUI. I already have a compiled binary but I need one with python support, so I have to compile it myself

Comment: I mean a JTAG device, such as the Segger J-Link, in the case you would want to  debug an embedded system. I understand this is not the case.

Comment: You are correct, this is not the case. I just want the Insight debugger for the arm-none-eabi architecture with python support

Comment: In this case, I would strongly suggest you to install [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)  on your Windows 10 PC and to build Insight in it the same way you built it on the RaspberryPI. With WSL2, and as much as I have loved them, Cygwin's and Mingw64's days are now over IMHO.

Comment: Do you mean cross compiling it?

Comment: No, I mean compiling it natively on Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64 on WSL2 for the same arm-none-eabi target, and  running it natively above WSL2,  in  a WSL2 bash session/window on your Windows 10. Does this make sense ?

Comment: It makes sense. However, I prefer to have it natively on windows. Is there anything I can do to fix the error mentioned?

Comment: Be prepared to spend a lot of time fixing insight for Windows, because 1.5 years ago I also tried to do this. I was able to get an executable, and while it looked nice, it was completely unusable. When trying to do anything, it either showed weird error messages, or hung completely.

Comment: @Stepil I made a mistake suggesting to build Insight on WSL2, this would not be practical because it would require an X11 server running on Windows 10. Again, I would suggest  using GDB in TUI mode or Elipse Standalone Debugger.